# QT unable to detect input files while displaying image to qLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qlabel

While attempting to display an image resource from my `.qrc` file with usage ":/logo-here", I keep getting an error saying

```
No input files specified.
```

Here is the compiler error segment

```
/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/rcc -name  ../VPN/.qrc -o qrc_.cpp
/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/rcc: No input files specified.
Usage: /opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/rcc [options] inputs
```

My `.qrc` file

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="logo">back.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I am able to open the image from the qt resource manager, thus qt does have the correct path, but somehow I am missing something...

Any advice?

**Extra Info:**

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    //QGraphicsView *view;
    //QGraphicsScene *scene;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap pixmapTarget = QPixmap(":/back.png");
    //QPixmap pixmapTarget = QPixmap(":/logo");
    ui->label->setPixmap(pixmapTarget );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**Full compiler output**

```
22:42:44: Running steps for project VPN...
22:42:44: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
22:42:44: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../VPN -I. -I/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include -I/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mainwindow.o ../VPN/mainwindow.cpp
/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/rcc -name  ../VPN/.qrc -o qrc_.cpp
/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/rcc: No input files specified.
Usage: /opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/rcc [options] inputs
Qt Resource Compiler version 5.7.0

Options:
  -h, --help           Displays this help.
  -v, --version        Displays version information.
  -o, --output <file>  Write output to <file> rather than stdout.
  -t, --temp <file>    Use temporary <file> for big resources.
  --name <name>        Create an external initialization function with <name>.
  --root <path>        Prefix resource access path with root path.
  --compress <level>   Compress input files by <level>.
  --no-compress        Disable all compression.
  --threshold <level>  Threshold to consider compressing files.
  --binary             Output a binary file for use as a dynamic resource.
  --pass <number>      Pass number for big resources
  --namespace          Turn off namespace macros.
  --verbose            Enable verbose mode.
  --list               Only list .qrc file entries, do not generate code.
  --project            Output a resource file containing all files from the
                       current directory.

Arguments:
  inputs               Input files (*.qrc).
Makefile:589: recipe for target 'qrc_.cpp' failed
make: *** [qrc_.cpp] Error 1
22:42:48: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project VPN (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
22:42:48: Elapsed time: 00:03.
```

Comment: Omit `-name` and set .qrc to the end. `-name` does not name your input file but the name of the function to be generated. Otherwise just append a `.qrc` as input file.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using `<qresource prefix="/">` so that you'll need to add an extra `/` to your resource path: `QPixmap("://back.png");`

Note: You can make use of Qt Creator and go to your resources from the files hierarchy on the left and right-click on the resource you want then choose to copy resource path, which is a path you can use.